# Question regarding back transformation of data

Tags: anova, t-test, data-transformation, back-transformation

I have a data set that boils down to accuracy levels in a response task.

In order to run an ANOVA on the accuracy data I've been advised to perform a arcsine square root transform on the data first.

Arguments for and against this type of transform aside, this is relatively straight forward.

My question is: Should I back transform the data when presenting means, MSE, etc.

Additionally if I perform any post-hoc tests (such as t-test) should I do that with the untransformed means, transformed data, or back transformed means?

Thanks for your time.